# IDEA sharing settings

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm

I want to share exported settings from webstorm to other IDEA-s for example pycharm etc... Is exported settings compatible with other IDEA-a, so that for example I import webstorm settings to pycharm and then modify some settings in pycharm and again import exported settings from pycharm to webstorm. Would this action be safe so nothing would be corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you would corrupt any settings. However, some settings may get dropped. For example, if there is a setting that is available in WebStorm, but not PyCharm, PyCharm may "drop" that setting. When you go to import back into WebStorm, that setting would be lost.

The reason I say that is that ultimately the settings export/import are copies of the XML configuration files in IDEA's `config` directory. (See [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) for information on its location. The path should be similar for WebStorm and PyCharm.) When PyCharm imports the settings, it is just replacing the various setting XML Files. But then when PyCharm runs, upon loading and re-saving the settings file, it *may* drop elements that are not applicable. (My *suspicion*, is that it would not, but you'd have to test to be sure.)

Another option from using the settings import/export would be to just do a diff between the two `config` directories using a good diff tool like [Beyond Compare](http://scootersoftware.com/).

This is an unusual activity, so there's probably not many people that have actually done (or tried) this. As such, unless someone from the JetBrains development team comes on to definitively say one way or the other, I think your best bet is to just try and see. Of course, backup your settings before doing an import from the other tool :)

Comment: Tnx for your suggestion... I have created repo that is helping to control the versions of settings... https://github.com/urosjarc/IDE.Intellij :)